# ArcMap add in constructor called not called on start up

Tags: arcobjects, add-in, toolbar

I am converting some old tools to the new Add-In format and have noticed that the constructor is no longer being called during startup, instead it is being called when the tool is clicked for the first time (second and subsequent call OnActivate only).

This particular tool is in a toolbar add-in and is of type ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool and should only be enabled if ArcMap is currently editing. Previously the constructor was called and set the tool.enabled = false arbitrarily (as you can't be editing on startup) and added an event handler for IEditEvents_OnStartEditingEventHandler which set the too.enabled = true (and stop editing too, enabled = false).

Now that the tool is made into an add in I discovered by step-debugging that the constructor for the tool isn't called until the tool is clicked. After clicking the tool behaves in the intended manner as the events are wired. Is there a way to call the constructors during ArcMap startup, soon after or does anybody know of any other workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [`config.esriaddinx`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000001ms000000), set the tool's [`onDemand`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001v000001tr000000) property to `false`. Similarly, if you have any extensions that need to be initialized at startup, set its [`autoLoad`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/001v/001v00000234000000.htm) property to `true`.

Comment: I'm not seeing that property, is it something that I could add?

Comment: Yes, try adding it if it's not there.

Comment: That did it thank you @blah238! the use of the onDemand and autoLoad is optional. I inserted the properties onDemand="false" autoLoad="true" on the line that started <Tool id= and it ran the constructor as before.

Comment: Only onDemand applies to Tools so you can remove autoLoad (applies to extensions).