# Executing function on start up/ on started ArcMap in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.4

I need execute a function that init a timer when ArcMap application start. 
My extension class:

```
namespace GMREAddin.Modules.Toolbar
{
    public sealed class eManager : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
    {
       protected override void OnStartup()
       {
            MessageBox.Show("opened from onstartup.");
            initTimer();
       }
    }
}
```

And have this attribute in the configuration
[image]

When I run the application, it doesn't display the message, and does not start the message.

I am using version 10.4.

Answer (score 2):

According to [ArcMap add in constructor called not called on start up](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94406) it looks like you need to add a 'delayLoad' attribute to your extension and set it to false. Then also keep autoLoad = "true".

I created an empty sample project and tested this code. The config extension looks like this and it seems to work:

```
<ArcMap>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension id="ArcMapAddin1_Extension1" class="Extension1" delayLoad="false" autoLoad="true" />
  </Extensions>
</ArcMap>
```

And then I have a MessageBox in the OnStartup() method which appears as soon as ArcStarts.

```
protected override void OnStartup()
{
   MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
}
```

Comment: I get the message: The 'delayLoad' attribute is not declared. And in the post isn't that attribute

Comment: I edited my answer with the test I ran for this. What version of ArcMap are you running? The example above is 10.2.

Comment: I run the version 10.4

Comment: Okay, when using 10.4 I also see the 'attribute is not declared' error, but I can still build and run the add-in. Is it preventing you from building your add-in?

Comment: No, my application run. But the event doesn't work.